# What is the minimum android version fro libs-for-android filecache?

Tags: android, caching

The git repository includes a jar for Android 2.2. Can I use filecache in lower versions of Android, such as 1.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a response from the author, he said that 1.6 does indeed work.